# Markov chains: finding state space and transition matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $N=2,3,4,...$. We have $2$ urns with $N$ marbles in each. $N$ of the $2N$ are white and $N$ of the $2N$ are black. Each step a random marble from each urn is taken and switched. The state is the number of white balls in the the first urn.

Find the state space and the transition matrix.

I think the state space is $\{0,1,2,...,N\}$, given that the number of white marbles in urn 1 can be $0$ to $N$. So there are $N+1$ states.

If we let the current state be $n\in\{0,1,2,...,N\}$ then the number of white marbles in the first urn is $n$ and $N-n$ in the second. The number of black marbles in the first urn is $N-n$ and $n$ in the second.

I'm not entirely certain how to do it, but I figure there are 3 cases.

Case 1: You draw a white from the first urn and a black from the second urn.

Case 2: You draw a black from the first urn and a white from the second urn.

Case 3: You draw the same color.

Any ideas/hint on how to proceed?

Comment: So, you have a state space, and you've identified the non-zero transition probabilities. It is left to calculate them and write as matrix.

Answer (score 2):

There are $N$ white marbles. Say current state is $0\leq n\leq N$, then next state is the same if same color is drawn from both. This has probability $2 * n/N*(N - n)/N$.

$n$ increases by $1$ if we draw black and white. Probability: $((N - n)/N)^2$
$n$ decreases by $1$ if we draw white and black. Probability: $(n/N)^2$

All other probabilities are $0$ so the matrix becomes tridiagonal:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
2\ \ 0/N\ \ (N-0)/N & \left(\frac{N-0}{N}\right)^2 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2 & 2\ \ 1/N\ \ (N-1)/N & \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^2 & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 0 & \left(\frac{2}{N}\right)^2 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
 \vdots  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \left(\frac{N-N+1}{N}\right)^2 \\
 0 & \cdots  & 0 & \left(\frac{N}{N}\right)^2 & 2\ \ N/N\ \ (N-N)/N \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will just go over it myself later today, and see if I reach the same probability for when n increase and decrease. I'll update later in the comment field and mark this answer as solved (for the archive)